# Do Django ORM database queries block the server, or are they asynchronous?

Tags: database, django, asynchronous, orm, twisted

I just want to clarify few things.

I believe that Django server works asynchronously (because if every request from the client would block server then it wouldn't work), but I know also that the Django ORM isn't async. So do queries to the database block the server? (I mean that rest requests are waiting until the query is complete?) Or maybe it works completely differently and I misunderstood it.

I'm asking this because I heard that most ORMs are blocking and hence I can't use them in my Twisted server to get data from db without blocking twisted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why would the server need to work asynchronously? Django is a WSGI application; the concurrency model depends on the server you run it in, and that can be threading, multiprocessing, asynchronous (select loop driven) or a combo of those.

Each Django request itself is *completely synchronous*. Querying the database blocks the request until the result is returned. It doesn't need to be aware of other, concurrent requests (other than ensuring that Django handles data structures in a thread-safe manner).

Comment: Then I don't get some simple things. Everywhere I hear that async > sync, yet Django is sync. How does it work so well (I know it might be thread for another SO question, but it just bothers me).

Comment: And that means I can't make a request from Django to another service asynchronously, to example get data from RESTful API?

Comment: Async may be faster when doing a lot of I/O, it is also *harder* to work with. But good caching layers help mitigate and smooth over the differences. There is nothing in standard Django to help with async requests to external RESTful APIs, no. You could look at Celery, a great async worker architecture that integrates very well with Django.

Comment: I never tried sync programming. I was always intuitively writing async apps and it's harder for me to imagine how it really works. Thanks for answer. One more question, if I will make sync request in a django view to another site, django request will wait until I get data from that call and then return response itself? I just want to call twisted server from within django to make twisted do something.

Comment: Yes, if you use the standard `urllib2` library or `requests` (which have no async support) then that code runs synchronously and you end up waiting for the twisted server to return a response.

Comment: and it will not block another requests, so I can safely use it with many requests to server? That is relief.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I was doing it before with in example online payment and calls to PayPal. Stupid me.

Comment: "Why would the server need to work asynchronously?" Well because then you can make several parallell requests to different data sources found on socket-like objects like databases, REST APIs and files.. and then produce a result potentially much quicker than if doing several synchronous operations in series.

Comment: This has to be one of the most obtuse answers I've seen on SO in ages. A professional-class system will have dependencies on many data sources, SQL, memcache, s2s rpcs, you name it. If these things can be done in parallel, they should be. Even on a fairly basic system, you'll have celery doing batch processing of management tasks. While you're burning CPU on the processing of a batch of rows, you want your next batch of data to be in transit from the data source. Django - to put it mildly - sucks at this. Threads are your friends.

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus: Sure, and that's why you configure your WSGI server to use threading and / or multiprocessing. The question was assuming that Django somehow needed to handle the concurrency. It doesn't, not out of the box, it leaves that to the WSGI *server* (where Django is the WSGI app plugging into that server). That's not to say you can't add on asynchronous handling within a request handler, see the [Django Workload project codebase](https://github.com/Instagram/django-workload/blob/master/django-workload/django_workload/feed.py) for an asyncio sample. Disclaimer, I wrote that code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the similar problem as you seem to be having. My django application performs a lot of calls to rest services to render the view and it bothered me they had to be serialized. 
I developed this:

https://github.com/kowalski/featdjango/

This is a application server based on twisted web. Unlike the django-on-twisted project it doesn't use the wsgi at all. Django code is run in a thread. There is a pool of them. Twisted code runs in the main application thread and manages the pool. If you need to do a few calls from the Django code and can benefit from doing it simultaneously you need to create a method, which returns a Deferred (or DeferredList). Than, from django code, you can call it by:

```
import threading
...

ct = threading.current_thread()
result = ct.wait_for_defer(method_to_call, *args, **kwargs)
```

This has the effect of calling the *method_to_call* with reactor.callFromThread() method and binding the callbacks to wake up the caller thread. The result of the Deferred is returned, or the exception is raised (in case when the errback() is fired).

Comment: I will probably run django and twisted on separate machines so it won't work in my case, but thanks for answer.

Comment: Its also my case. I have a django and twisted components. But sometimes the django view needs to perform more than one call to twisted. Than I benefit from what I have explained.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. But I won't be performing more than one requests to Twisted and I will do it relatively rarely.